# How to pass data outside foreach?

Tags: swiftui

I have a for each; how can I pass the foreach item to the outside view in SwiftUI?

```
struct exerciseplan: View {

    @State var showdetai = false
    var textView: some View {
     ForEach(data), id: \.element) { model) in
       Image(model.image)
        .onTapGesture {
                        showdetai = true
                    }
       Text(model.exercisename)
    }}
    
    var body: some View {
            
            ZStack{
    if showdetai{
          Text(model.exercisename)
                  }
            textView
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the question is here and it's compounded by the fact that the code you've included is filled with syntax errors (it can't be your real code -- it wouldn't compile). Can you explain more about what are you trying to do? `model` gives you the item inside `ForEach` -- you pass it to another view just like you're already doing with `Text(model.exercisename)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new State variable to hold the selected model. You can make it an optional if you need to

E.g (assuming your model is of type “model”. So you would need to define the correct type here.

```
@State var selectedModel: model?
```

then within your on tap gesture you set the new state variable to the model.

```
selectedModel = model
```

Comment: True - posted from phone and it autocorrected the capital letter. I have now edited to correct this. Thanks